# Enforce SQL Server NAtive Client 11.0 while using SQLCMD

Tags: sql-server, sqlcmd

SQLCMD is by default using SQL Server Native Client 10.0 which is throwing below eror

```
T:\mno\pqr>sqlcmd -S 192.168.29.3 -U abc -P def -d ghi -i "jkl.sql"
HResult 0x15, Level 16, State 1
Encryption not supported on the client.
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 10.0 : Client unable to establish connection.
HResult 0x80090331, Level 16, State 1
SSL Provider: The client and server cannot communicate, because they do not possess a common algorithm.

Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 10.0 : A network-related or     instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL     Server. 
Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. 
For more information see SQL Server Books Online..
```

I need to reinforce SQL Server Native client 11.0 which fixes this issue (tried and tested via SSIS) but cant find the procedure. Please help

Comment: You need to install a newer version of SQLCMD to use a newer driver.

Comment: I cannot find the installed sqlcmd in any of the below folders
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\80\Tools\Binn
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Tools\Binn
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn

Comment: Try this folder: `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\130\Tools\Binn`

Comment: The 64-bit version of SQLCMD 11.0 would be in `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn`.  Later versions will be in the `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\nnn\Tools\Binn`, where nnn is the version.

Comment: You can find details on  how to download the latest version of sqlcmd in it's documentation: [sqlcmd Utility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlcmd-utility?view=sql-server-2017)

Answer (score 0):

Try this folder: `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\130\Tools\Binn`

It works on mine:

[image]